# How to implement a class to decide for Ok or bad request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I'm looking for a solution to improve my code.

I have in all my controllers this code:

```
var data = await _accountService.Create(value);
if (data.HasError)
{
    return BadRequest(data);
}
return Ok(data);
```

I'm looking for a solution where I don't need to do this If to check if HasError Exist.

In all my services I return the following class:

```
public class ResponseEnvelope<T>
    {

        public T Result { get; set; }

        public IList<ErrorDto> Errors { get; set; }

        public IList<MessageDto> Messages { get; set; }

        public bool HasError
        {
            get
            {
                return Errors != null && Errors.Any();
            }
        }

        public bool HasMessage
        {
            get
            {
                return Messages != null && Messages.Any();
            }
        }

        public ResponseEnvelope<T> AddError(string code, string message = null, string description = null)
        {
            Errors.Add(new ErrorDto(code, message, description));
            return this;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could also look into Middleware (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1). In the middleware you could add a try/catch. Then instead of returning that `HasError` you could throw (custom)exceptions that are caught by the middleware, which in return will handle the BadRequest.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right and you just invoke a method on servoce and return its response wrapped, then add an extension method to `Controller`:

```
public IActionResult WrapResponse<T>(this Controller controller, ResponseEnvelope<T> envelope){
    return envelope.HasError ? controller.BadRequest(envelope) : controller.Ok(envelope);
}
```

and invoke it as `this.WrapResponse(data)`

Answer (score 0):

**.Net Core**

You can extract this functionality using [ActionFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1#action-filters) or [Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Action Filter has `OnActionExecuted` - and you can place this logic there.

I would prefer to use **Middleware**  you cand do this after the call `next.Invoke()`

**.Net Framework**

If you are using .Net Framework there are a few options like [IHttpHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ihttphandler.processrequest?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_IHttpHandler_ProcessRequest_System_Web_HttpContext_), IHttpModule and ActionFilter. You can read about modules and handlers there [IHttpHandler vs IHttpModule](http://ihttphandler-vs-ihttpmodule)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to archive it was to implement a middleware capable of understanding the response from the API.

Because I return always an Envelope with Data and Errors (if they exist) the middleware was very simple.

Also because I have middleware I was able to implement a single point of log.

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            Stream originalBody = context.Response.Body;

            using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                context.Response.Body = memStream;
                await _next(context);
                memStream.Position = 0;

                //get response body here after next.Invoke()
                var reader = new StreamReader(memStream);
                string responseBody = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseBody) && !responseBody.StartsWith("["))
                {
                    JObject json = JObject.Parse(responseBody);
                    if (json.ContainsKey("hasError") && (bool)json["hasError"] == true)
                    {
                        _logger.LogError($"{_correlationContext.CorrelationContext.CorrelationId} {responseBody}");
                        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api/authentication/users"))
                        {
                            _logger.LogInformation($"{_correlationContext.CorrelationContext.CorrelationId} Logged");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _logger.LogInformation($"{_correlationContext.CorrelationContext.CorrelationId} {responseBody}");
                        }
                    }
                }

                memStream.Position = 0;
                await memStream.CopyToAsync(originalBody);
                context.Response.Body = originalBody;

            }
```